# How to call laravel url root from wordpress themes

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel

I have wordpress inside laravel directory (public/blog). I want to call laravel url root on the theme of wordpress. If i call a function like home_url() or site_url() on theme of wordpress it will show root of wordpress (www.example.com/public/blog). I want to call laravel url root like www.example.com/public. How to do it?

Location of wordpress

[image]

Comment: www.your-site.com

Comment: how do  i get the image from laravel public directory in the wordpress theme sidebar? can i do it?

Comment: try giving the full path like www.your-site.com/imageFolder/file and see if this works?

Comment: wow this work perfectly... thankyou very much

Comment: you're welcome..